# output panel is showing error while saving visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, outputlink, outputpanel

I have added text and hyperlink based on the if condition but it is showing error

> The element type "apex:outputpanel" must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag

`</apex:outputpanel>` but it is already closed

```
<apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!showSign}">
    {!IF(signStatus == 'Unsigned',"please click on the link "+ <apex:outputLink value='{!slink}'>click here </apex:outputLink>, "please click on the "+ <apex:outputLink value='{!slink}'>click here </apex:outputLink> +" download file")}
</apex:OutputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to generate the visualforce dynamically, the other simpler way I can think of is to write two output links and render it based on your conditions.

Your visualforce page which would work would be

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showSign}">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(signStatus == 'Unsigned', true, false)}">
        please click on the link <apex:outputLink value="{!slink}"> click here </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(signStatus == 'Unsigned', false, true)}">
        please click on the  <apex:outputLink value="{!slink}"> click here </apex:outputLink> download file
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```